# Hive UDF + JNI + cleanup?

Tags: java, hive, udf

I'm writing some Hive UDFs, using JNI to talk to a native C library. The C library requires some expensive initialization, and maintains its internal state via a handle. To avoid re-initializing at every row, I initialize the library on the first row, then store the handle as a static variable in the Java world and fetch that for subsequent rows. This is all working fine.

The tough part is that the library also requires you to do cleanup, to release that internal state. Being Java, there are no destructors, of course. And I can't rely on 'finalize'. So I can't figure out where to clean up this library.

Is there anything in the Hive + UDF world that will tell my Java code when the query is finished, so that I can cleanup that library? Or, is there any Java mechanism that I can use to do this?

I'm using the 'UDF' class not 'GenericUDF', but I don't think that matters. I don't see anything in either that looks like a cleanup (GenericUDF's 'close' doesn't ever get called, AFAICT).